# Prevent hook_form_alter to works only on frontend not in admin?

Tags: views, 7, webforms, forms

I have used a hook_form_alter to alter a form fields value randomly and its working fine, but the problem is that when i open this webform in admin panel its just change the value  which i dont. Its should keep the same value which is submitted by frontend user. i want this hook to work in case of frontend only not for admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple admins, then check with user role, lets have admin_role as a Admin role

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  if(in_array('admin_role', $user->roles)) {
    return;
  }
 else {
    //alter fields logic goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: this is better! but I personally think that having multiple admins is not good from the security perspective.

Comment: This is not meaning we are in admin pages, just check the current user role is `admin_role` in everywhere

Comment: This is going to apply everywhere not just in the admin area. And it won't work if there are multiple roles which can access the admin area.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the global variable [`$user`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7) to achieve it.

```
<?php

function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  if($user->uid == 1) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    //alter fields logic goes here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should implement some check for the user roles of admin like this.

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  $adminroleid = 1 ; // It should be id for admin role, you should change this according to your's admin role id.

  if(array_key_exists($adminroleid, $user->roles)) {
    return;
  }
 else {
    // write your's form alter fields logic here .
  }
}
```